# How can consumption tax be useful on a good which is not being sold?

Tags: victoria-3

I noticed in my market tab that there is a demand for **luxury clothes**, although there are no **sell orders**. From this I conclude that this good is not being sold (is this wrong?).

It is still possible to set a **consumption tax** on the good, which has effect and improves my budget.

This does not make sense to me. If no goods are being sold/consumed, a tax should have no effect on the budget.

Either I misunderstood some of these mechanics, or this is poorly implemented in the game. Which is the case? If anyone understands the details, please explain.

[No sell orders for luxury clothes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kqXr.jpg)

[Consumption tax improving my budget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cT5mK.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**, goods are being sold:
[image]

**Yes**, consumption taxes are being paid:
[image]

## From where the goods come from?

Government officials **can't** answer that. That is the reason why there are no sell orders in the market window.

These are to the player imagination:
**black market, smuggling, second-hand market**.